# Convert Maven Desktop App to Dynamic App in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, web, dynamic

I have a Maven based desktop App and I have to convert it to a dynamic web app in eclipse or any other IDE ( I am using Eclipse Neon-Java EE). 
I have tried with Project Facets (Right click on project name --> Properties --> Project Facets --> dynamic web app) It generates some files but it doesn't seem to be converted to web as in the project folder still appears the letter "M" and not the golobe icon. When I try to run it in Tomcat it doesn't work.

[Project Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73hB4.png)

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: this letter "M" means this project have a maven nature , it does not mean it is not dynamic

Comment: Ok it may be dynamic but it isn't yet web right?

Comment: it might be check your project structure if new files appeared (WebContent,web.xml ...)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the project if you have the Maven convert option...

If not, you should check the property of the project, and change them manually, starting from the Deployment Assembly, the target runtime, check all the facets..

Then take a look into the folder of the project, into .classpath and .project and see if they have been refreshed by Eclipse, the pom should package as a war and so on...

The problem here is that you are fighting with Maven and Eclipse togheter, so my main suggestion to do this in lees time, is to create a new Dynamic project and then to copy and paste all the previous Desktop project.. you can do this in a lot of ways...

Or directly from the IDE, or simply by hand than importing again the project...

Let me know if you try one of the above suggestions :)

Moreover obviously after all of this it won't start in tomcat, you have before to configure your web.xml and so on... but at least your structure will follow the Dynamic Web Project structure standards..